# C Language - different definitions of function due to global variables

Tags: c, function, c-preprocessor, signature

Can I have a function that gets defined differently due to value of some global variable -for example called "s"?
It should accept two integers if s equals 0, and one character otherwise.

I've tried using C preprocessor, but it seems that global variables cannot be accessed while preprocessing is being done.

```
# include <stdio.h>

int s = 1;
# if (s == 0)
void f(int x, int y);
# else
void f(char x);
#endif

int main(){
    if (s == 0) f(0, 1);
    else f('z');
    return 0;
}
```

Surprisingly, in the above code f will be defined to accept two arguments, which logically is not expected.
I also do not want to change the main function.

Comment: You can't use variables in the preprocessor. In the preprocessor condition `s == 0` the ***macro*** `s` is undefined and therefore equal to zero.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in this way

```
    # include <stdio.h>
    
    #define S
    
    # ifdef S
    void f(int x, int y);
    # else
    void f(char x);
    #endif

    int main(){
        
        # ifdef S
        f(0, 1);
        # else
        f('z');
        #endif

        return 0;
    }
```

And if you want to run the "else" version you just put the definition of S in a comment `//#define S`